# Maven Checkstyle and Effective POM

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I created a new maven project and wanted to run an initial **checkstyle** check against it using a custom checkstyle ruleset. I went ahead and ran *mvn checkstyle:check*, not expecting it to work without first adding checkstyle to my pom, but to my surprise it did. That is, maven downloaded the checkstyle jar to my local .m2 and ran *checkstyle:check* on my project.

I find this surprising is because I have not added checkstyle to my pom; nor do I see any reference to checkstyle in the effective pom (*mvn help:effective-pom*); nor does does checkstyle show as a dependency (*mvn dependency:tree*).

So how is maven aware of checkstyle at all? What is the elusive source within maven of the checkstyle tool and what additional features are available from that source?

I'm hoping the answer will also provide insight into how to tell *mvn checkstyle:check* to use a custom ruleset, not just the [predefined](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/index.html)  *google_checks.xml* or *sun_checks.xml*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I tell mvn checkstyle:check to use a different ruleset, say google_checks.xml, rather than sun_checks.xml, which it seems to use by default

Use the `configLocation` parameter, which specifies the location of the XML configuration to use: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful, but I ended up re-wording my question because I had phrased it wrong. I really was wondering about how checkstyle works even without showing in the effective pom or dependency tree.

Comment: @JWoodchuck Ok, this is because of the [default maven plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) - plugins that you do not need to define in your pom.xml but still you can call them by invoking `mvn plugin:goal`

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for (default/supported maven plugins, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html). Thanks!